# Change array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is an array

```
[ [ 'Alex', '167%' ],
  [ 'Benjamin', '127%' ],
  [ 'Elijah', '117%' ],
  [ 'Liam', '136%' ],
  [ 'Theodore', '135%' ],
  [ 'Mia', '128%' ] ]
```

I need to make it look like this

```
[ 'Alex                     167%',
  'Benjamin                 127%',
  'Elijah                   117%',
  'Liam                     136%',
  'Theodore                 135%',
  'Mia                      128%' ]
```

I need the elements of each nested array to be combined into a string and such a number of spaces are inserted between them so that the length of this string is 29 characters

Comment: Uh-huh, that handily tells us what you *do* know. Unfortunately however, you've forgotten to tell us what you'd like to know - a practise usually covered by asking a question. What's yours?

Comment: I came across a hinge trying to solve. What if a name is 30 letters long?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: name will definitely not consist of more than 20 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)

```js
const items = [
  ['Alex', '167%'],
  ['Benjamin', '127%'],
  ['Elijah', '117%'],
  ['Liam', '136%'],
  ['Theodore', '135%'],
  ['Mia', '128%']
];


const combined = items.map(([name, percent]) =>
  name.padEnd(29 - percent.length, ' ') + percent
);

console.log(combined);
```